# Find 3 parameters so that the expression is valid

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm finding it difficult to do this problem, its part of the system of linear equations with three variables. Find a,b,c so that for every x ∈ R this is valid:

$$x^2=a(x+2)^2+b(x+2)+c$$

Any help is appreciated, even if its just a tip on what to look for

Comment: Consider expanding the right-hand-side and combining like terms. Then use the fact that every element of a finite-dimensional vector space can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of vectors in a given basis. Can you go from there?

Comment: I tried a suggestion with rewriting my left polynomial as 1⋅x^2+0⋅x+0 but then c=0 and that isn't correct. Tried expanding the right side and combining like terms, but i end up in a even bigger mess

Comment: Are you sure that you imposed the right conditions?

Comment: “Even bigger mess?” Collect terms and compare coefficients of the two polynomials, and you end up with a simple system of linear equations in the unknown coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Look at the coefficients of the polynomial to the left (you can also write it as $1\cdot x^2+0\cdot x+0$) and expand the square on the right , what system of $a,b,c$ you should solve to make the same polynomial on both sides?

Hint 2 : if you expand the right side you get $ax^2+(4a+b)x+4a+2b+c$ so you should impose : $   \begin{cases} a = 1\\ 4a+b=0 \\ 4a+2b+c=0\end{cases}  $

to make the two sides equal.

Comment: thank you very much for this tip

Comment: I updated the answer :)

Comment: I always feel stupid after seeing stuff like this, it all looks easy in the end, i was way off in my thinking and how I was going about the problem.